# What is the flow of this program?

Tags: python

i am a beginner in python...i wrote this code expecting output as,

```
global name:xxx
derived class
base class
globally declared function has been called
globally declared function has been called
```

but i got the following output,

```
Global name:xxx
derived class
derived class
base class
None 
Globally declared function has been called
Globally declared function has been called
```

What is actually the logic? Where do I go wrong?

Here is my code:

```
Name=raw_input("Global name:")
def display():
    print "Globally declared function has been called"
class base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bname='base class'
        print self.bname
    def bfun1(self):
        display()
class derived(base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dname="derived class"
        print self.dname
    def bshow(self):
        self.bsname=raw_input(super(derived,self).__init__())
        print self.bsname
        display()
ob=derived()
ob.__init__()
ob.bshow()
ob.bfun1()
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You do *not* need to call `.__init__()` explicitly. It is already called when you create your object; `ob = derived()` invokes `.__init__()` for you.

Later on, in `bshow()` you call `base.__init__()` explicitly, but wrapped in a `raw_input()` call. Because `base.__init__()` doesn't have an explicit `return` statement (which it should not have), `raw_input()` prints the *default* return value for functions, `None`.

The following code would come closer to what you expected:

```
Name=raw_input("Global name:")

def display():
    print "Globally declared function has been called"

class base(object):
    def __init__(self):
        self.bname='base class'
        print self.bname

    def bfun1(self):
        display()

class derived(base):
    def __init__(self):
        self.dname="derived class"
        print self.dname
        super(derived, self).__init__()

    def bshow(self):
        self.bsname=raw_input()
        print self.bsname
        display()

ob=derived()
ob.bshow()
ob.bfun1()
```

Comment: I got the output.. but still after getting "derived class" in output, the "globally declared function has been called" is printed only after we press Enter key.. why is that like so?..

Comment: Because both your code and my code call `raw_input()` in the `.bshow()` method. If you don't want user input there, remove that call!